# $routeChangeStart and similar not working on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

In my angular webapp,

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/topic/:keyword/heath-feed', {
        controller: 'hfController',
    })
    .when('/topic/:keyword/heath-feed/:storyType', {
         controller: 'hfController',
    })
```

In the above route configuration for ng-route, $routeChangeStart and $routeChangeSuccess events get triggered as expected for **'/topic/:keyword/heath-feed'**. But they're not triggered for **'/topic/:keyword/heath-feed:storyType'** route. I added an extra $routeChangeError block to check if the route isn't being resolved properly, but that block isn't being triggered as well.

The problem exists both for internal routing and on directly landing on page/reloading.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
        ...
    })

$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, next, current) {
       ...
    });
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
       ...
    });
```

These are the route listeners that I am using.

Any clue?

Comment: Route changing or not?

Comment: Yes, route is changing, controller is invoked and all functions are working properly. Baffled by just this bit. *sigh*

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or plunker of it?

Comment: Replicating would be really cumbersome. Will rather work it out or wait out if someone would have encountered something similar, *secretly wishes* at some point in time.

Answer (score 0):

State has not been changed as you have assigned a same controller for both the routes. Since, both the route represents same controller, It might not reflect on routeChange.

Comment: I have over 15 route configs and 6 controllers, and $routeChangeStart works everywhere else. *yells* *sigh* This shouldn't be the case.

Comment: Also, shouldn't state depend on ngView rather than which controller is being assigned?

Comment: can you please provide more information on this? It's hard to figure out the issue see this much information provided.